# Assert execution of an if statement in unit test

Tags: java, kotlin, unit-testing

I have a kotlin code like:

```
internal class ClassA
@Inject
constructor(private var fileCreator: FileCreator) {
  internal fun doA() {

    var file: File? = null

    try {
      // do something 
      file  = fileCreator.create()
    } catch (e: IOException) {
      throw e
    } finally {
        if (file.exists()) {
          file.delete()
        }
    }
  }
}
```

How do I write a unit test that verifies whether the `file.delete()` line above is run or not?
I cannot mock `fileCreator`, it is doing some real stuff.

Comment: Mock `fileCreator` so that `create` returns a Mock `File`, and check that the mock has had `delete` called on it.

Comment: If you cannot mock `fileCreator` then you're not really unit testing `ClassA`. A unit test is a test of a single (hence "unit") class or method, in isolation from all other dependencies.

Comment: By the way, there's no reason to call `file.exists()` - just call `file.delete()` and it won't delete it if it doesn't exist. Better still, get your `fileCreator.create()` to return a `Path` instead of the legacy class `File`. Then call `path.deleteIfExists()`.